# Testing a getter that calls another getter, without mocking - or how to mount Vuex in tests?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm failing to understand something fundamental using Vuex: For a store that runs perfectly fine in the application, when running tests, due to dependency injection none of my getters that call other getters work.

See the following store that has two getters:

```
const state = {
  items: {},
}

const getters = {
  item: (state) => (itemIndex) => {
    return state.items[itemIndex]
  },
  reducedItem: (state, getters) => (itemIndex) => {
    return getters.item(itemIndex).reduce((acc, subitem) => {
        return acc + ';' + subitem.text
    }, '')
  }
}

const mutations = {
}

const actions = {
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

And an example test:

```
import DemoStore from '@/store/modules/DemoStore'
import { expect } from 'chai'
const getters = DemoStore.getters

describe('store/DemoStore', () => {
  it('reducedItem reduces', () => {
    var state = {
      items: [
        [{text: 'a'}, {text: 'b'}, {text: 'c'}],
      ]
    }

    let result = getters.reducedItem(state, getters)(0)
    expect(result).to.equal('abc')
  })
})
```

When running the test, the `reducedItem` getter calls `getters.item` which instead of calling `getters.item(state)` and returning a proper value, calls the plain `getters.item` function, which returns a function. Therefore the code in testing environment is simply not working.

I understand Vuex recommends mocking getters but come on, it's not serious to consider mocking so deeply.

Is there a way to "mount" the vuex store in tests in order to use it exactly as in the application ?

Comment: Did you try to just create the store, `new Vuex.Store(DemoStore)`?

Comment: Neat, missed the obvious thing here!

Comment: @EstusFlask if you want to add an answer I'll validate it

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DemoStore` is options object that is provided to Vuex constructor. Vuex can be created like:

```
let store = new Vuex.Store(DemoStore);
```

Getters are supposed to be available as `store.getters` and behave like it's expected from Vuex store.